# mini-SAS SFF-8087 xy connector and 24 hard drives?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, colocation

I have

24x drive 4U case with 4U Expander Backplane
http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/4u/846/sc846e16-r1200.cfm

MegaRAID SAS 9260-4i RAID Card
http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/storagecomponents/Pages/MegaRAIDSAS9260-4i.aspx

One sff-8087 to sff-8087 cable

The question is can 24 drives run of this RAID card and single cable via the expander backplane optimaly or do I need to invest in a more expensive RAID card such as 
LSI MegaRAID SAS 9280-4I4E

Answer (score 1):

It is a SAS card, so it can deal with a SAS backplane. RTFM to find out how many discs the card can handle.

Comment: I guess what I want to know is can a single mini-SAS SFF-8087 cable run 24 drives, but seems it doesnt matter now, this site is very user unfriendly it seems with the closing of the thread

Comment: SAS is a network protocol. The cable has plenty of bandwidth. This is not unfriendly here, but for people in "professional capacity". Asking beginner questions is - not welcome. We keep quality above "I am clueless".